# How to force exclusive ownership of a file for FileStream

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, filestream, streamreader

To read a file that's already opened by another process, you usually do something like this.

```
var outStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, 
                               FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Is there a way to achieve the opposite effect? In other words, have a program exclusively own the file and make sure that no other processes can read the file until the stream has been closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FileShare` with option `None` this will give you

> Declines sharing of the current file. Any request to open the file (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx)

Your Code should be :

```
using (Stream iStream = File.Open("c:\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open,
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    //your code here
}
```